# Git log 2 tags and filter commits for a particular path

Tags: git

I have a repository that has many different folders and tags. I want to list out commits between 2 release tags for a particular folder.

I've tried `git log --oneline -- ${folder path} tag1 tag2` and it seems to filter to only the commits in specified folder path, but it seems to be showing more commits than the diff between tag 1 and tag 2.

Is there a way to list out the commits between 2 different tags for a particular specified folder path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of problems here:

- Everything after the `--` option is taken to be a file name.  (This lets you look for a *file* named `master`, for instance.)  So `tag1` and `tag2` here are treated as file names—they're not referring to any commits.  Solving this problem is easy as you just need to move `tag1` and/or `tag2` to the other side of the `--`.
- The whole concept of *between* is tricky, because commits are not necessarily all in a nice neat row.  Solving this is potentially much harder: *you* must decide what *you* mean by *between*.
- When you give path names to `git log`, this enables what it calls *History Simplification*.  Whether this is actually a problem at all for your particular usage is also a hard question, but solving it, *if* it is a problem, is actually pretty easy: just add `--full-history` to disable History Simplification.

So you probably want:

```
git log --oneline --full-history <something with the tags> -- <folder-name>
```

with the `--full-history` needed only if some commits seem to be missing from the result.

#### Let's tackle the *`something`* part

First, remember that each commit, in Git, holds a full and complete snapshot of all files, along with some *metadata* about that snapshot: who made it (author name, email, and date-and-time-stamp plus the same again for committer), a log message, and—most important for us right now—the raw hash ID of some set of *previous* commits, which Git calls the *parent* or *parents* of this commit.

Each commit has a unique, big ugly hash ID.  This is in effect the true name of the commit.  All other names, whether they are branch names like `master`, tag names like `v2.1`, or relative names like `HEAD~3`, are just a way to have Git find the raw hash ID.  Meanwhile, each name—including branch and tag names—just holds *one* hash ID.  When that one hash ID is a particular commit,<sup>1</sup> that's the commit named by the branch or tag.  We say that the name *points to* the commit.

But since commits *also* contain commit hash IDs, commits *also* point to commits.  Indeed, this is exactly how history comes about in a Git repository.  A name—typically a branch name like `master`—points to the *last* commit, by holding its hash ID.  If we let `H` stand for the actual hash ID, we can draw it like this:

```
              H   <-- master
```

Meanwhile, though, commit `H` contains the hash ID of its parent commit.  Let's call that `G`, so that `H` points to `G`:

```
          G <-H   <-- master
```

Of course `G` has its own parent.  Let's call that `F`, which also has *its* own parent, and so on:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master
```

That's a nice simple linear chain of commits.  If there are just eight commits in the repository, all in a row like this, we can draw them as:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- master
```

For laziness and lack of angled-direction arrows, I'm now using lines instead of arrows to connect the commits, but remember that they're all actually backwards-pointing arrows.  We can go from commit `H` *back* to `A`, but not *forward* from `A` to `H`, using the internal arrows.

(Commit `A` is special: as the very first commit someone made, it *can't* have a parent, so it doesn't.  Git calls this a *root commit*.  Every non-empty Git repository has at least one root commit.  That's where we can stop going back, when we look at the history.)

To add a new commit to some branch, Git just writes out the new commit with an arrow pointing back to the *current* commit, and then writes the new commit's actual hash ID into the branch name.  For instance, to get from:

```
...--G   <-- master
```

to:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
```

Git just wrote new commit `H` with parent hash `G`, then wrote the actual hash of `H` into the name `master`.

But Git history often *isn't* linear like this.  People make new branches, and then make new commits *on* those branches, which leads to drawings like this:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H--L   <-- master
         \
          K   <-- br2
```

Someone might subsequently do `git checkout master; git merge br1` to re-merge branch 1 into `master`, which produces:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /    \
...--G--H--L---M   <-- master
         \
          K   <-- br2
```

New merge commit `M` points back to *both* `L` (as its first parent) *and* `J` (as its second parent).

> **Trick question:** Which branch is commit `H` on?
>
> **Answer:** It's actually on *all three* branches.  Git is peculiar here: many version control systems save which branch a commit is *made* on, and that's the branch the commit is on, forever.  Git doesn't save this information anywhere.  A commit is on a branch if you can *reach* that commit by *starting from* the commit to which the branch name points.  So, from `master`, we can work back to `H` in one hop from `L`, or two hops from `M` once we add `M`.  From `br1`, we can work back to `H` in two hops: starting at `J`, go to `I`, then `H`.  From `br2` we go `K` then `H`.  So `H` is on *all three* branches.

---

<sup>1</sup>Branch names are constrained to hold only commit hash IDs, so branch names automatically point to a commit.  Tag names are less constrained: they can point directly to a commit, in which case Git calls them *lightweight* tags.  Or, they can point to a *tag object*, which has its own unique hash ID.  The tag object then points to another object—usually a commit—so that the tag still points to a commit, but indirectly, through the tag object.  This is how you can make an *annotated* tag with extra information, such as release notes or a GPG signature.

---

#### Between is tricky

Let's take one of these sorts of graphs and add a few tag names, which point to specific commits just like branches, but aren't necessarily at the *end* of a branch.  (In particular, once you make a tag name, you're supposed to let it point to that same commit, by its hash ID, forever.)  So we might have:

```
     tag:v0.7    tag:v0.8
        |           |
        v           v
...--G--H--I--M--N--O--P   <-- branch1
      \
       J--K--L   <-- branch2
          ^
          |
       tag:v0.9
```

Which commits are "between" tags `v0.7` and `v0.8`?  I think most people would agree that it's `I-M-N`, or maybe `H-I-M-N-O`, or something like this.

But: which commits are "between" tags `v0.7` and `v0.9`?  Which ones are between `v0.8` and `v0.9`?  I think a lot of people will disagree.

What if it turns out that commit `M` is actually a merge, not a regular commit, and the drawing should look like this instead:

```
     tag:v0.7     tag:v0.8
        |            |
        v            v
...--G--H--I---M--N--O--P   <-- branch1
      \       /
       J--K--L   <-- branch2
          ^
          |
       tag:v0.9
```

Now which commits are "between" the various tags?

What Git gives you—**all** that Git gives you—is the ability to walk the actual graph, whatever it is, with various modifiers.  Git does this by starting towards the end—at a commit like `P`, for instance—and working *backwards*, in the only direction it can actually work, with those backwards-pointing arrows that connect the commits.

Any branch or tag name you give to `git log` counts as either:

- a starting point: a commit you want to work backwards from, or
- a stopping point: a commit you want Git to *not* include, *nor any of its ancestors*.

For instance, suppose we have that first graph:

```
     tag:v0.7    tag:v0.8
        |           |
        v           v
...--G--H--I--M--N--O--P   <-- branch1
      \
       J--K--L   <-- branch2
```

and we tell Git: *Start at `P`, but stop at `L`*.  Obviously starting at `P` doesn't actually ever get us *to* commit `L`, because we go `P`, `O`, `N`, `M`, `I`, `H`, `G`, and so on.  But by telling Git *stop at `L`* we really mean *stop at any commit **reachable from** `L`:* all of `L`, `K`, `J`, `G`, and so on backwards are stopping-points.

The syntax we might use for *start at `P` but stop at `L`* is:

```
branch2..branch1
```

which means *all commits reachable from the tip of `branch1` (i.e., `P`), excluding all commits reachable from the tip of `branch2` (i.e., `L`)*.

This same syntax works for tag names.  In fact, it works in the exact same way: just mentioning a tag name, as in `git log v0.8`, means *consider the commit to which this tag points as a starting point*.  Mentioning *two* tag names, with two dots between them, means *consider the commit to which this tag points as a stopping point*.  So:

```
v0.7..v0.8
```

would start at `O` and stop at `H`.  This will exclude commit `H`, i.e., it will look only at commits `O`, then `N`, then `M`, then `I`.

If the name `v0.9` points to commit `K`, `v0.9..v0.8` will look at commits starting with `O` and working backwards until it stops at `G`.  It doesn't matter that `0.9` comes after `0.8`.  Git isn't using those numbers at all.  Git is exclusively using the *graph* to include or exclude various commits.

When there are merges in the graph, things get tricky.  Here, you might sometimes want an additional flag, `--ancestry-path`.  But like `--full-history`, this starts to get kind of complicated, so we probably should stop here.

I can't resist mentioning a third option, though, as some people will want this when they say "between".  Besides the two-dot syntax `stop..start`, there's a *three*-dot syntax.  This means *all commits reachable from either name, except for all commits reachable from **both** names*.  That is, given:

```
...--G--H--I--M--N--O--P   <-- branch1
      \
       J--K--L   <-- branch2
```

the syntax `branch1...branch2` means commits `H-I-M-N-O-P` *and* commits `J-K-L` (but not in that order, since Git has to work backwards).  The *excluded* commits start at `G` and work backwards, since `G` is on both branches.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the syntax almost right.

To list a range of commits, use `tag1..tag2`, and place all commits before the `--`.  So your command should look like the following:

```
git log --oneline tag1..tag2 -- path
```